# Change image on $mdDialog after some interval

Tags: angularjs

I want to  use a slider type effect on my `$mdDialog`, the image src comes from server.I tried using `$interval` but it din't work for me.

When user logs in, he will see a pop-up, on that pop-up all the available 
images are shown one after another.
I have all the image's src on controller in a scope variable, but how can i dynamically change the image src.

This is what i tried

```
        i=0;
        $scope.ShowIndex = i;
        $interval(incrementProofData, 1000);
        function incrementProofData(){
                $scope.ShowIndex = i;
                i++;
       }
```

This is my html code

```
         <img src="{{popAssetMenu[ShowIndex].ExternalUrl}}" style="width: 100%; height: 100px; margin: 2em 0 0 0;">
            </div>
```

Comment: try using `ng-src` instead of `src` if it won't work you should create custom directive and handle this logic using `ng-if` .

Comment: `ng-if ` will delete element and then crate it again so src will automatically get update.